# TypeError -Fastapi sample fails during loading

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying fastapi for the first time and using the sample code in the document.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

I also installed required packages before executing

```
pip install "fastapi[all]" 
pip install uvicorn
```

And the execution failed with TypeError.

```
uvicorn model_sm:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/name/workplace/flask']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [24303] using StatReload
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 59, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 66, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 471, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/name/workplace/flask/model_sm.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fastapi import FastAPI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 16, in <module>
    from fastapi import routing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 478, in <module>
    class APIRouter(routing.Router):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 497, in APIRouter
    lifespan: Optional[Lifespan[Any]] = None,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 277, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 768, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params, len(self.__parameters__))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 97, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a generic class")
TypeError: typing.Union[typing.Callable[[ForwardRef('Starlette')], typing.AsyncContextManager[NoneType]], typing.Callable[[ForwardRef('Starlette')], typing.AsyncContextManager[typing.Mapping[str, typing.Any]]]] is not a generic class
```

I couldn't find anything helpful in the search. Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: By the way, I can get a successful run in linux. The above failure is in my mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the uvicorn command depends on Python3.9 for execution. So I reinstalled all the following package using pip3.9, which fixes the issue.

```
pip3.9 install typing-extensions
pip3.9 install uvicorn
pip3.9 install fastapi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install fastapi
```

- try to install fastapi using above command it workes for me.
- if you are using macOS or linux you should use the folloing command.

  `pip3 install fastapi`
- befor running this script open-up terminal and import **FastAPI** to ensure it works correctly. then run this script.

Comment: Above commands works fine in mac. However ```uvicorn model_sm:app --reload``` still fails

Comment: it works fine with me in my macOS. 
**Here is what you can do**:

1. create a virtual environment using `python -m venv <virtual_environment_name e.g. env>`.

2. activate vertual environment using `source <virtual_enivronment_name>/bin/activate`.
3. then install packages `pip install fastapi uvicorn`.
4. copy your python script to the current directory.
5. run your app using `uvicorn model_sm:app`.
6. i hop this fixes the issue.

Comment: No, it is not helpful